# Equivalence classes of $\mathcal R = \{ (X,Y) \in S\times S : |X| = |Y| \}$; $S=$ set of all finite subsets of $\Bbb{N}$??

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory

I'm having trouble with the following exercise:

> Let S be the subset of all finite subsets of $\Bbb{N}$. Let
>   $\mathcal{R}$ be a relation defined as $\mathcal{R} = \{ (X,Y) \in S\times S
>  : \operatorname{card}(X) = \operatorname{card}(Y) \}$
>
> How many different equivalence classes does $\mathcal{R}$ have? Find
>   the simplest possible representative for each class.

I would tend to think that the number of equivalence classes in this relation is infinite.

For example:

Let $X= \{ 1;2;3\}$. Let $Y = \{ 4; 5; 6\} $.

$$(\{ 1;2;3\},\{ 4; 5; 6\}) \in S\times S \text{ and } \operatorname{card}(X) = \operatorname{card}(Y)$$

$\overline{X} = \overline{Y} = (\{ 1;2;3\},\{ 4; 5; 6\})$

And in general, one can come up with infinitely many examples with the following format:

$$X = \{ a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_i \} \text{ where } a_i \in \Bbb{N} \ \forall i$$

$$Y = \{b_1,b_2,\ldots,b_n \} \text{ where } a_n \in \Bbb{N} \ \forall n$$

If $i = n$, then $X \mathcal{R}Y \text{ and } Y \mathcal{R}X$

$\overline{X} = \overline{Y} = (\{ a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_i \},\{b_1,b_2,\ldots,b_n \})$

However, I haven't been able to prove this and the fact that I'm asked to find the simplest representative for each class leads me to think that maybe my conjecture is wrong and there is a finite number of equivalence classes.

**Can anyone help me? If the number of different equivalence classes is infinite, how can I prove it? And if it is finite, why is it so?**

Comment: Yes, countably many classes. The sets $\emptyset,\left\{0\right\},\left\{0,1\right\},\left\{0,1,2\right\},..$ are representatives of each class. In fact, if $Y\in S$ then $card(Y)$ is some finite cardinal $n$ therefore $Y$ is in the class of $\left\{0,1,2,...,n-1\right\}$.

Comment: @Hellen I would have taken $S_0=\emptyset,S_1=\{1\},S_2\{1,2\},S_3=\{1,2,3\},...$ to have $|S_k|=k$ but I agree with you :).

Comment: I can't choose between these two... Thanks guys you destroyed my day :(

Comment: Proper notation is $S\times S,$ not $SxS.$ I edited accordingly.

Comment: Sorry but what is the question exactly?

Comment: I initially asked 2 questions: (1) Is the number of equivalence classes infinite? . (2) If it is infinite, how do I prove it? . The first question has been answered here in the comment section. The second one is still not clear to me.  If my understanding is correct, Hellen and Surb are giving examples of equivalence classes of this relation, but they are not proving that there are infinitely many of them.